# Load and execute python scripts from a local path after python console is triggered in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-2.7

I had created a file named "startup.py" in users python home directory `(... .qgis2/python)` and I had triggered the python console in `startup.py` file by

```
import qgis

qgis.utils.iface.actionShowPythonDialog().trigger()
```

That successfully triggers console as soon as QGIS opens. Now I want python scripts from local path to be loaded and executed in the console automatically using PyQGIS. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

Add these lines to `startup.py` file.

```
from qgis.utils import iface

def test():
    print("Successful")

iface.actionShowPythonDialog().triggered.connect(test)
iface.actionShowPythonDialog().trigger()
```

[image]

OR

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from foo import bar

iface.actionShowPythonDialog().triggered.connect(bar)
iface.actionShowPythonDialog().trigger()
```

If you want to run the script while opening a project, add those lines to `openProject` method in "Project Properties > Macros". And then you should add the highlighted line in the script below. Otherwise, when every clicking the "Python Console" button, `bar` method runs.

```
def openProject():
    from qgis.utils import iface
    from foo import bar
    iface.actionShowPythonDialog().triggered.connect(bar)
    iface.actionShowPythonDialog().trigger()
    iface.actionShowPythonDialog().triggered.disconnect(bar)
```

*foo.py*:

```
def bar():
    print("Successful")
```